# Error "com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter cannot be converted to javax.servlet.Filter"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, azure, azure-aad

Error "incompatible types: com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad.AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter cannot be converted to javax.servlet.Filter"

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto Java en IntelliJ. Estoy utilizando Spring Framework 6 y Spring Boot 3, y quiero utilizar la biblioteca de Microsoft Azure para autenticación con Azure Active Directory. Agregué la dependencia correspondiente en mi archivo pom.xml, como sigue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
        <version>1.41.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Sin embargo, cuando intento utilizar la clase AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter que se encuentra en el paquete com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad, el compilador me muestra el siguiente error:

```
package com.microsoft.azure.spring.autoconfigure.aad does not exist
```

He revisado mi archivo pom.xml y estoy seguro de que la dependencia está incluida. También revisé mi entorno de desarrollo para asegurarme de que no hay problemas con la configuración de mi proyecto. ¿Alguien sabe qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Aquí está mi configuración:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1
Windows 11
JDK 17
```

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.